# Консольная игра на pascal. Пару вопросов.

Tags: pascal, разработка-игр

Пишу курсовую другу. Необходимо сделать в консоле игру на подобия арканоида тетриса, только нужно не шариком, а стрелять из управляемой пушки.

Я вижу написания игры таким образом, поправьте если не так:

1. создам матрицу;
2. заполню ее нулями - это пустые клетки;
3. потом размещу на ней первый уровень, например единицами;
4. два к примеру пушка;
5. функция прорисовки будет регулярно вызываться и рисовать в консоле то объект то пушку;

Собственно возникли следующие вопросы:
Как убрать прокрутку в консоле? То есть, вот как в самом турбопаскале: Запустил, и ничего не прокручивается.
Как мне лучше перехватывать нажатия клавиш-стрелочек и пробела(можно другую клавишу назначить на FIRE)?
Как добавить задержку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прокрутки там не будет, если вы не будете вылезать за отведенные 80х25 символов.
Для этого используйте

```
gotoxy(x;y)
```

а перед всем -

```
clrscr;
```

стрелки можно считывать так:

```
while KeyPressed do begin
  key := ReadKey;
end;
```

Comment: О, есть прогресс. Спасибо! Буду пробовать.

Comment: А как сделать задержку?

Comment: Функция Delay:

    for i:=0 to 10 do
     begin
      //...
     delay(ms);
    end;

Comment: Что тяжело у меня с отрисовкой. Создал объект World массив из объектов Figure. У Figure есть oType, который определяет что это(квадрат, треугольник). А вот как это прорисовать что-то не догоню. Ну clrscr и gotoxy понятно, а вот с объектами х.з..

Comment: Просто делай еще один `gotoxy` и заново введенные символы будут затирать старые.

Comment: Это я понимаю. Вот у меня к примеру есть матрица 3 х 3 из объектов 2 х 2. Как зная тип объекта правильно ее прорисовать? А то у меня выходит что я рисую первый элемент, потом второй частично, потом перехожу на новую строку и затираю предыдущий.

Comment: Надо написать процедуру(или цикл), которая в качетсве аргументов будет принимать тип объекта и координаты верхнего левого угла.
А тело будет примерно следующим:

    if celltype="monster" then
      symbol = "#";
    if celltype="player" then
      symbol = "@";
    if celltype="empty" then
      symbol = " ";
    gotoxy(x;y);
    write(symbol);
    gotoxy(x+1;y);
    write(symbol);
    gotoxy(x;y+1);
    write(symbol);
    gotoxy(x+1;y+1);
    write(symbol);